# Как взять строку из textfield

Tags: java, javafx

Как взять данние из textfield javafx

Comment: `textfield.getText()`, см. тут например: https://metanit.com/java/javafx/4.5.php или в официальной документации: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут 2 варианта развития событий.

Если вы используете FXML разметку, то вы, вашему объекту там, присваиваете id. Чтобы объект был доступен в коде, вы объявляете его в контроллере с таким же id.
Чтобы другие классы видели id вашего элемента, нужно передавать им экземпляр контроллера.
Ну и после всего этого вы можете юзать `.getText();`
С этим вам хорошо поможет разобраться SceneBuilder.

Если это внутрянка, то

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
String z = tf.getText();
```